# PyTorch - Neural Network - Output single scalar value

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch, reinforcement-learning

Let's say we have the following neural network in PyTorch

```
seq_model = nn.Sequential(
nn.Linear(1, 13),
nn.Tanh(),
nn.Linear(13, 1))
```

With the following input tensor

```
input = torch.tensor([1.0, 1.0, 5.0], dtype=torch.float32).unsqueeze(1)
```

I can run forward through the net and get

```
seq_model(input)

tensor([[-0.0165],
        [-0.0165],
        [-0.2289]], grad_fn=<TanhBackward0>)
```

Probably I also can get a single scalar value as an output, but I'm not sure how.
Thank you. I'm trying to use such an network for reinforcment learning, and use it
as an value function approximator for game board state evaluation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first dimension of input represents the number of observations in your minibatch (3), the second dimension represents instead the number of features (1).

If you want to forward a single 3d input, the network must be modified (`nn.Linear(1, 13)` becomes `nn.Linear(3, 13)`), and you must remove `unsqueeze(1)` on `input`. Otherwise, you can merge the three outputs by using a loss to compute a single scalar from them.

Comment: thanks, your hint abount how input/feature size is set helped to input right. Regarding having one output value, rather then using mean, the last layer outputs a tensor with one elment.